# Traversing through the Json object

Tags: json, pyspark

I have a json file which has the following data:

```
    {
  "glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
      "title": "S",
      "GlossList": {
        "GlossEntry": {
          "ID": "SGML",
          "SortAs": "SGML",
          "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
          "Acronym": "SGML",
          "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
          "GlossDef": {
            "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
            "GlossSeeAlso": [
              "GML",
              "XML"
            ]
          },
          "GlossSee": "markup"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I need to read this file in pyspark and traverse through all the elements in the json. I need to recognize all the struct, array and array of struct columns and need to create separate hive tables for each struct and array column.

For Example:

**Glossary**  will be one table with "title" as the column

**GlossEntry** will be another table with columns "ID", "SortAs", "GlossTerm", "acronym", "abbrev"

The data will grow in the future with more nested structures. So i will have to write a generalized code which traverses through all the JSON elements and recognizes all the structs and array columns.

Is there a way to loop through every element in the nested struct?

Answer (score 1):

Spark is able to automatically parse and infer json schema. Once its in the spark dataframe, you can access elements with the json by specifying its path.

```
json_df = spark.read.json(filepath)
json_df.printSchema()
```

Output:

```
root
 |-- glossary: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- GlossDiv: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- GlossList: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- GlossEntry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Abbrev: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- Acronym: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- GlossDef: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- GlossSeeAlso: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- para: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- GlossSee: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- GlossTerm: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- SortAs: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
```

Then choose the fields to extract:

```
json_df.select("glossary.title").show()
json_df.select("glossary.GlossDiv.GlossList.GlossEntry.*").select("Abbrev","Acronym","ID","SortAs").show()
```

Extracted output:

```
+----------------+
|           title|
+----------------+
|example glossary|
+----------------+

+-------------+-------+----+------+
|       Abbrev|Acronym|  ID|SortAs|
+-------------+-------+----+------+
|ISO 8879:1986|   SGML|SGML|  SGML|
+-------------+-------+----+------+
```